# Getting TypeError: missing x required positional arguments

Tags: python

So i've been messing with this code for the past hour or so but I can't get anywhere without running into a different error. I feel like this version is the least amount of errors compared to the other versions.

This is my code

```
#Variables
import random
count_2s = 0
count_3s = 0
count_4s = 0
count_5s = 0
count_6s = 0
count_7s = 0
count_8s = 0
count_9s = 0
count_10s = 0
count_11s = 0
count_12s = 0
user_input = 0
index = 0
die_1 = 0
die_2 = 0
dice_total = 0


#User Functions
def one():
    user_input = input('How many times to roll the dice?:')
    user_input = int(user_input)
    return user_input

def two():
    dice_total=0
    while index < user_input:
        die_1 = random.randint(1,6)
        die_2 = random.randint(1,6)
        dice_total = die_1 + die_2
    return dice_total, index

def three(dice_total, count_2s, count_3s, count_4s, count5s, count_6s, count_7s, count_8s, count_9s, count_10s, count_11s, count_12s, user_input):
    print("2's rolled: " , count_2s, "or %5.2f percent" , count_2s/user_input * 100)
    print("3's rolled: " , count_3s, "or %5.2f percent" , count_3s/user_input * 100)
    print("4's rolled: " , count_4s, "or %5.2f percent" , count_4s/user_input * 100)
    print("5's rolled: " , count_5s, "or %5.2f percent" , count_5s/user_input * 100)
    print("6's rolled: " , count_6s, "or %5.2f percent" , count_6s/user_input * 100)
    print("7's rolled: " , count_7s, "or %5.2f percent" , count_7s/user_input * 100)
    print("8's rolled: " , count_8s, "or %5.2f percent" , count_8s/user_input * 100)
    print("9's rolled: " , count_9s, "or %5.2f percent" , count_9s/user_input * 100)
    print("10's rolled: " , count_10s, "or %5.2f percent" , count_10s/user_input * 100)
    print("11's rolled: " , count_11s, "or %5.2f percent" , count_11s/user_input * 100)
    print("12's rolled: " , count_12s, "or %5.2f percent" , count_12s/user_input * 100)



def main(index):
    one()
    two()
    if dice_total == 2:
        count_2s = count_2s + 1
    elif dice_total == 3:
        count_3s = count_3s + 1
    elif dice_total == 4:
        count_4s = count_4s + 1
    elif dice_total == 5:
        count_5s = count_5s + 1
    elif dice_total == 6:
        count_6s = count_6s + 1
    elif dice_total == 7:
        count_7s = count_7s + 1
    elif dice_total == 8:
        count_8s = count_8s + 1
    elif dice_total == 9:
        count_9s = count_9s + 1
    elif dice_total == 10:
        count_10s = count_10s + 1
    elif dice_total == 11:
        count_11s = count_11s + 1
    elif dice_total == 12:
        count_12s = count_12s + 1
    index = index + 1
    three()

main(index)
```

And this is the error I receive:

```
How many times to roll the dice?:200
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Julian/Desktop/Python Stuff/lastone.py", line 78, in <module>
    main(index)
  File "C:/Users/Julian/Desktop/Python Stuff/lastone.py", line 76, in main
    three()
TypeError: three() missing 13 required positional arguments: 'dice_total', 'count_2s', 'count_3s', 'count_4s', 'count5s', 'count_6s', 'count_7s', 'count_8s', 'count_9s', 'count_10s', 'count_11s', 'count_12s', and 'user_input'
```

Any step in the right direction would be appreciated, thanks!
I realize some steps maybe be user defined functions but that's just how it has to be done.

Comment: Call function `three()` with all the parameters defined in function definition.

Comment: The function `three` needs 13 arguments and you are calling it with 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems here, lets start from the top:

```
def one():
    user_input = input('How many times to roll the dice?:')
    user_input = int(user_input)
    return user_input
```

This method returns a value, but when you call it, down in `main()`:

```
def main(index):
    one()
    two()
```

You never save the return value. Now, you may be thinking that since you defined `user_input = 0` at the very top of the script, `one` will use the `user_input` you initialized.

This isn't how things work in Python.  A function has its own scope. This means, that variables defined inside the function have no relation to variables outside of the function. To get things into a function, you pass them in, and to get things out of a function, you return their values *and then store them*.

You have the same problem with `two()` as it return a tuple, but you don't store it - thus, you never have the results of the calculations in your `main()` method.

The reason for the error you are getting is because you have defined function `three` as taking 13 arguments, all are required. Yet, when you call the function you don't pass anything in:

```
three()
```

You need to pass in the arguments, like this:

```
three(dice_total, count_2s, count_3s etc. etc.)
```

Of course, before you do that, make sure you are capturing the return values from your other methods.

Comment: That's a generously thorough answer. I would also note that the general approach could be greatly improved by using a dictionary or a list so that excessive variables don't need to be created. As a rule, you don't want to have multiple variables that represent related values. It's more efficient and cleaner to adopt an alternative storage structure.